# TypeError for derivative function

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, derivative, calculus

I used sympy to find derivative of a function.

()=−5+√(4−^2)

```
import sympy
def f_derivative(x):
  x = sympy.Symbol('x')
  f = x - 5 + (4 - x**2)**0.5
  derivative_f = f.diff(x)
  derivative_f = sympy.lambdify(x, derivative_f)
  print(derivative_f(1))
f_derivative(1)
assert f_derivative(1) - 0.42264973 < 1e-5
```

However, there is an error when I use assert to check

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'**

Please let me know how to fix it

Comment: `f_derivative` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import sympy
def f_derivative(x):
  x = sympy.Symbol('x')
  f = x - 5 + (4 - x**2)**0.5
  derivative_f = f.diff(x)
  derivative_f = sympy.lambdify(x, derivative_f)
  result = derivative_f(1)
  assert result - 0.42264973 < 1e-5
  print(result)
f_derivative(1)
```

I hope helped you